# JSON serializer instead of JSV in ServiceStack ORMLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Despite that JSV promoted as faster and more compact alternative to JSON, it's not supported by many platforms and databases, while JSON is.

How to make ServiceStack ORMLite serialize and de-serialize using JSON format instead of JSV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes OrmLite supports [pluggable text serializers](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/complex-type-serializers) which lets you specify different serialization strategies of Complex Types for each available RDBMS provider, e.g:

### Pluggable Text Serializer Examples

```
//ServiceStack's JSON and JSV Format
SqliteDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new JsvStringSerializer();       
PostgreSqlDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new JsonStringSerializer();
//.NET's XML and JSON DataContract serializers
SqlServerDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new DataContractSerializer();
MySqlDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new JsonDataContractSerializer();
//.NET XmlSerializer
OracleDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new XmlSerializableSerializer();
```

You can also provide a custom serialization strategy by implementing IStringSerializer.

By default all dialects use the existing `JsvStringSerializer`, except for PostgreSQL which due to its built-in support for JSON, uses the JSON format by default.

Comment: In my tests this actually solves a problem with deserializing nested objects serialized as JSV. In my test a Dictionary<string,object> where object could be another Dictionary, was serialized to JSV but only deserialized 1 level deep (using LoadSingleById). With JSON it worked with many levels.